# restoreCompleteTransaction issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I tried to restore&download content from completed transactions by using the following scenario It's asking password to enter.

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    //   Written code for restoring and downloading.
}
```

when ever I enter password and submit, the file content downloading successfully.
 And Here is the problem **If i pressed cancel from popOver where it will ask password to enter it's not calling any method alas it's not showing any alert**

What will be the issue can anybody help on this....

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found some solution myself

```
 - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Restore Transaction Cancelled");
}
```

Thank you